# из си вызвать метод класса lua

Tags: c, lua

У меня есть следующий код на Lua (test.lua)

```
test = {}
test.new()
  print("new")
end
return test
```

как из СИ вызвать метод new()?
вот такой код не срабатывает (test.cpp)

```
lua_State *L;
L = luaL_newstate();
luaL_openlibs(L);
luaL_dofile(L, "test.lua");

lua_settop(L,0);
lua_getglobal(L,"test");
lua_getfield( L, "new");
lua_pushstring (L, "параметр");
lua_pcall (L, 1, 1, 0);
```

PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (attempt to index a nil value)
2 Аварийный останов

Answer (score 1):

У вас код на Lua написан неверно. Если вам нужно объявить функцию внутри таблицы, то это можно сделать вот так:

```
test = {}

test.new = function(param1)
  print(param1)
end

return test
```

А ещё лучше, не засорять глобальное пространство имён и писать модули в таком стиле:

```
local new = function(param1)
  print(param1)
end

return {
  new = new
}
```

После выполнения этого кода из Си, на стеке будет лежать анонимная таблица, у которой вы можете дёргать нужные методы:

```
luaL_dofile(L, "test.lua");
lua_getfield(L, -1, "new");
lua_pushstring (L, "my_param");

if (lua_pcall(L, 1, 1, 0) != 0) {
    printf("Func call failed: %s", lua_tostring(L, -1));
    lua_pop(L, 1);
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Ответ `zed` содержит ряд неточностей и фактических ошибок, так что дам отдельный.

Код на `lua` и правда написан неверно. Объявить функцию в таблице и правда можно, как указал `zed`, но для метода есть особый синтаксический сахар:

```
test = {}

function test:new(param1)
  print(param1)
end

return test
```

(такой манерой любые функции объявить можно, вроде `local function help()`).

В данном коде

```
function test:new(param1)
```

эквивалентно
    function test.new(self, param1)
При вызове через `test:new('11')` аргумент `self` получит значение `test` (что вам, скорее всего, нужно, если это метод).

При таком написании правильнее и правда не засорять окружение, а писать так:

```
local test = {} -- обратите внимание на `local`

function test:new(param1)
  print(param1)
end

return test
```

Код C переписывать у `zed` не буду, только скажу, что из C нужно передать объект (таблицу) первым аргументом (в функции она будет `self`).

Comment: Никаких **ошибок** в моём ответе нету, т.к. функция намеренно не принимает `self`. Функции в таблицах можно объявлять как с `self`, так и без него. Соответственно, и вызывать такие функции надо по разному (из Си или Lua). Чтобы вызвать функцию без `self` из Lua, нужно писать так: `test.new("test")`, а из Си - так как указано в моём ответе.

Comment: @zed автор спрашивал именно про метод, а не функцию из таблицы.

Comment: В Lua нету классов и методов, но есть таблицы и функции. Поэтому, что конкретно хотел автор вопроса, можно только гадать. В примере его кода нету и слова о том, что ему нужен доступ к каким-то внутренним/приватным структурам таблицы. Поэтому, таков и ответ.